# Is it possible to get the height of soft navigation layout?

Tags: android, d-pad

Is it possible to get the height of soft(virtual) navigation layout? If yes, How to get the height programmatic ally?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank u for response.Its not work.It return 0 even the device has soft navigation layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
```

To get screen metrics wiithout soft navigation layout

```
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getMetrics(metrics);
int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

To get screen metrics with soft navigation layout

```
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRealMetrics(metrics);
int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

When you subtract the usableHeight from the realHeight, you get the actual height of the soft navigation layout.

Note: getRealMetrics() method will work only if the Api level is greater or equal to 17 otherwise it won't work. So check the build version before getting display metrics